# issue in installing cordova in windows 8

Tags: cordova, npm

when i try to install cordova for my windows machine  , this error keeps on coming, what is wrong here ?

i have updated npm before installing cordova .

is there any way to install cordova other than from CLI ?

```
 C:\>npm install -g cordova
npm WARN engine cordova-js@3.8.0: wanted: {"node":"~0.10.x"} (current:      {"node":"
0.12.1","npm":"2.5.1"})
 npm WARN engine npm@1.3.4: wanted: {"node":">=0.6","npm":"1"} (current:     {"node":
"0.12.1","npm":"2.5.1"})
npm WARN engine xmlbuilder@2.2.1: wanted: {"node":"0.8.x || 0.10.x"}       (current: {
"node":"0.12.1","npm":"2.5.1"})
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.2.9200
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program      Files\\nodejs
\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "cordova"
npm ERR! node v0.12.1
npm ERR! npm  v2.5.1
npm ERR! file C:\Users\Mahesh EU\AppData\Roaming\npm-   cache\xtend\4.0.0\package\p
ackage.json
   npm ERR! code EJSONPARSE

npm ERR! Failed to parse json
npm ERR! Unexpected token
npm ERR! File: C:\Users\Mahesh EU\AppData\Roaming\npm-   cache\xtend\4.0.0\package\ 
package.json
npm ERR! Failed to parse package.json data.
npm ERR! package.json must be actual JSON, not just JavaScript.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! This is not a bug in npm.
npm ERR! Tell the package author to fix their package.json file. JSON.parse
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.2.9200
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program    Files\\nodejs
\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "cordova"
 npm ERR! node v0.12.1
 npm ERR! npm  v2.5.1

npm ERR! Uncaught, unspecified "error" event.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\npm-debug.log

   C:\>
```

please help

Comment: Seems like the issue in in your `package.json` file. Try opening it in a text editor and removing the extra spaces in the file paths (like this one: `File: C:\Users\Mahesh EU\AppData\Roaming\npm-   cache\xtend\4.0.0\package\ 
package.json`)

Comment: that json file seems to be unreadable i can see only "nul nul nul" in black boxes written there. i opened in notepad++. how to recover this file ? i had a rar file named package in the same folder which when i extracted gave me another package.json. when i replaced it and run the command again, i still get the same issue

Comment: Cordova should be generating its own `package.json` file. Your current botched install sounds rather messy. You might want to remove all traces of cordova and reinstall (carefully). I'm assuming you followed [this](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/guide_cli_index.md.html) guide?

Comment: i was trying out ionic and i followed their guide. [http://learn.ionicframework.com/videos/windows-android/

Comment: thanks, it worked when i reinstalled npm.